# Using javascript array in mongodb operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to use javascript array in mongodb $in

It's always wrapping it with single quotes  // '"Indoor","Outdoor","Both"'

I need it to work or like this -> "Indoor","Outdoor","Both"

```
  url_parts.query.Venue ='Indoor,Outdoor,Both'

  var query={}; 

  if(url_parts.query.Venue!= undefined){

        var myarr  = url_parts.query.Venue.split(",");

        var string='';
        for (var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {

            string+="\""+myarr[i]+"\",";
         };

         string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1)

        query.venues = { $in:[string]};
    }

    attraction.find(query).lean().exec(function(err, attrs) {....
```

Comment: What is wrong with just passing in `myarr` as the argument to $in? `$in: myarray` would be valid as an argument. Or is there something wrong with your initial `split`?

Comment: I tried it it return venues: { '$in': [ [Object] ] }

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to show what `url_parts.query.Venue` actually looks like before you do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) takes an array:

```
var url_parts.query.Venue ='Indoor,Outdoor,Both';
var query = {};

query.venues = url_parts.query.Venue.split(",");
```

So now query looks like this:

```
{ "venues" : { "$in" : [ "Indoor", "Outdoor", "Both" ] } }
```

Comment: ok yes, you are right  i just had to remove the square brackets and it works . that you very much !!!!!!